# Entity model framework doesn't update properly

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using latest entity framework from nuget however the entity mapping is still not work correctly when DB changes. The procedure I am doing:

1. Set up synced entity model in code with DB table.
2. Change data type of some field in table.
3. Update entity model from DB.
4. The new data type is not updated.

There are still a few other scenarios that are not working that DB changes are not reflecting to entity model. I have read some articles and recognize these may be known issues already. However is there a common solution to resolve these issues? Right now I have to manually changes the data type in entity model source code. Is there some configuration change that can help the entity sync to be more accurate?

Comment: Will like to know too, same thing happen if you change something like `NULL` to `NOT NULL`

Comment: Does your entities follow any sort of inheritance?

Comment: I don't see any inheritance in my entities. It is created from an existing DB but I do see compositions for the FK relations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that Visual Studio is certainly able to detect the mismatch of data type of the column which was updated. This is why I'm seeing following error in "Error List" window as below. I changed the data type of Salary column from `Int` to `nchar(10)` in `Employee` table in my database:

```
Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Salary' in type 'DbFirstTpccModel.Employee' is not compatible with 'SqlServer.nchar[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=10,Unicode=True,FixedLength=True]' of member 'Salary' in type 'DbFirstTpccModel.Store.Employee'.
```

So to resolve this issue through update model wizard through which it detects data type changes it is better to simply delete the respective entity from model designer and then re-add the table through update model wizard.

Comment: My entity model doesn't work like this. I used "Update model from database..." menu after table field data type change but the change was not detected. If I delete that field in model and then update model, it creates a new field in entities with a new name with a suffix.